# How to restart camera efficiently in a fragment - Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I have two fragments in my app and I am trying to implement a barcode scanner using `ZXingScanner` library in one of them. The implementation works fine. My question is basically related to bad design.

When the user scans a valid code a dialog box appears saying the code is valid. But when i dismiss the dialog (by pressing OK) the barcode scanner stops. To address this issue i have the following:

```
buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    popupView.dismiss();
                    restartCamera();
                }
            });

public void restartCamera(){
    mScannerView.stopCamera(); //mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that when i switch the fragments the camera is still running behind. How can i stop the camera when i switch to first fragment and then turn it back on AND address this issue.
(I am using `ViewPager` to implement my fragments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution. I override my `setMenuVisibility` method in my camera fragment. If the fragment is visible call `restartCamera()` method otherwise stop the camera.

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible){
    if (visible){
        if (mScannerView != null) {
            Log.v("FragmentQR", "Visible");
            restartCamera();
        }
    }
    else {
        if (mScannerView != null){
            mScannerView.stopCamera();
            Log.v("FragmentQR","InVisible");
        }
    }
```